# MYSql Showing Symbol except Single Quot

Tags: mysql, quotes

Hello Developers: i have a problem with my mysql results. i have some textin mysql with single quot but after showing on my client side result it shows �  this symbol except single quot. in database talbe the text is like this:

```
text:   If money doesn’t grow on trees
Result: If money doesn�t grow on trees
```

Please let me know how it can be solved.
Regards & thanks.

Comment: That's a "smart quote" (well a single one), or a curved quote. Notice they don't look exactly the same: `’` vs. `'`. Curved quotes aren't supported in the ASCII codespace. What collation is your database set to?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://samjlevy.com/2010/11/php-replace-special-characters-before-mysql-insertion/) (note this is php, not sure what you are using).  You may want to pre-process to convert certain special characters.